# Align Flexbox differently when display size changes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following HTML/CSS code using Flexboxes:

```css
*{
 font-family:Arial;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}
.flexbox .header{
  background: green;
  border:solid;
  font-size: 30;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 5;
}
.flexbox .main {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
  position: relative
}

.flexbox-row {
  display: flex;
  position:absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}
.flexbox-row .links
{
  background: yellow;
  width:15%;
  height:100%;
}
.flexbox-row .second {
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
  height:100%;
}


nav.sidenav {
    margin:0;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: auto;
    height:100%;
}


nav.sidenav a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
}

nav.sidenav a.active {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}

nav.sidenav a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  nav.sidenav {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      position: relative;
      border-top:none;
      border-bottom:solid;
      margin-top:0;
      }
      nav.sidenav a {
          float: left;
          padding: 8px;
      }
  .flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: initial;
  width: 100%
  }
  .flexbox-row .links{
  width:100%;
  }
  .flexbox-row .second {
  background: blue;
}

}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">

<div class="header">HeaderHeaderHeaderHeaderHeaderHeade</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="flexbox-row">
    <div class="links">
      navbar
    </div>
    
    <div class="second"> content</div>
       
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I archive that when changing the display width the Flexboxes align like this:
[image]

So the header stays the same and then comes the navbar and the content. Filling up the browser height.
Iam new to css and dont quite understand how to properly use flexboxes.

Comment: Let me know if my answer were helpful and can be accepted and/or upvoted ... or it simply didn't work?

Comment: Since I didn't got any confirmation that my answered worked or were helpful, I deleted it.

Comment: Sorry wasn't able to Catch any internet the last few days.
Would be grateful to read your answer nonetheless.

Comment: Of course, have undeleted it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 main things:

- at narrower screens, using the media query, to put the `content` below the `links`
- remove absolute positioning and use Flexbox instead, so it will size properly with content

I added a lot of notes in the CSS, that explain what and why.

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial;
}

html,body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*flex-wrap: nowrap;           not needed, default value  */
  height: 100%;
  /*width: 100%                  not needed, default behavior  */
}

.flexbox .header {
  background: green;
  border: solid;
  font-size: 30;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 5px;         /*  need unit, added "px"  */
}

.flexbox .main {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
  /*position: relative;          not needed anymore  */
  display: flex;             /*  instead of absolute position  */ 
}

.flexbox-row {
  display: flex;
  /*position: absolute;          not needed anymore  */
  /*height: 100%;                not needed when parent has display: flex  */
  width: 100%;
}

.flexbox-row .links {
  background: yellow;
  width: 15%;
  /*height: 100%;                not needed when parent has display: flex  */
}

.flexbox-row .second {
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
  /*height: 100%;                not needed when parent has display: flex  */
}


nav.sidenav {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

nav.sidenav a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav.sidenav a.active {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

nav.sidenav a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  nav.sidenav {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: solid;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  nav.sidenav a {
    float: left;
    padding: 8px;
  }
  /*  not needed, already set
  .flexbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: initial;
    width: 100%;
  }
  */
  .flexbox-row {
    flex-direction: column;  /*  added, put content below navbar  */
  }
  .flexbox-row .links {
    width: 100%;
  }
  /*  not needed, already set
  .flexbox-row .second {
    background: blue;
  }
  */
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">

  <div class="header">HeaderHeaderHeaderHeaderHeaderHeader</div>

  <div class="main">  
    <div class="flexbox-row">
      <div class="links">
        navbar
      </div>
      <div class="second">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your media query (`@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {...`) , add

```
.flexbox-row {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

which places the child elements of `.flexbox-row` (i.e. `.links` and `.second`) below each other (-> `flex-direction: column;`), which is what you have in your image. Here is the modified snippet:

```css
*{
 font-family:Arial;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}
.flexbox .header{
  background: green;
  border:solid;
  font-size: 30;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 5;
}
.flexbox .main {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
  position: relative
}

.flexbox-row {
  display: flex;
  position:absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}
.flexbox-row .links
{
  background: yellow;
  width:15%;
  height:100%;
}
.flexbox-row .second {
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
  height:100%;
}


nav.sidenav {
    margin:0;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: auto;
    height:100%;
}


nav.sidenav a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
}

nav.sidenav a.active {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}

nav.sidenav a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  nav.sidenav {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      position: relative;
      border-top:none;
      border-bottom:solid;
      margin-top:0;
      }
      nav.sidenav a {
          float: left;
          padding: 8px;
      }
  .flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: initial;
  width: 100%
  }
  .flexbox-row .links{
  width:100%;
  }
  .flexbox-row .second {
  background: blue;
}
.flexbox-row {
  flex-direction: column;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">

<div class="header">HeaderHeaderHeaderHeaderHeaderHeade</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="flexbox-row">
    <div class="links">
      navbar
    </div>
    
    <div class="second"> content</div>
       
  </div>
</div>
```